# Setting the value of an input when using foreach in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am using the attr binding to set the name and value of an input tag. The problem is I don't know the binding to use for the value. I have tried text and value so far but with no luck. My code looks like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: witnesses">
    <input data-bind="attr: { name: 'firstName', text: firstName }"/>    
</div>
```

I am hoping that this will render as:

```
<input name='firstName value=`enter code here`'Joe'>
```

or even

```
<input name='firstName'>Jo`enter code here`e</input>
```

How to achieve this? Also, how do I get the index of the current iteration of the foreach loop, since I need to add this to my name..

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: witnesses">
<input data-bind="attr: { name: 'firstName' + $index()}, value: firstName"/>    
</div>
```

Here I'm concatenating the foreach index (zero-based) into the name of the input element. It's not actually necessary but since you mentioned it I assume you need it.

It would probably make more sense to use a css class if you're looking to identify all of those inputs.

Answer (score 1):

an instant solution . by the way you forgot the type attribute . you should set it.

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: witnesses">
         <input type="text" name='firstName' data-bind="value: 'enter code here ' + firstName"/>    
      </div>
```

and as others mentioned `$index` gives you index of current item in the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I shall check it out at work tomorrow. I'm quite sure I already tried using the value but I will try again.